# Passenger front wheel not centered

Tags: steering, chassis

I've noticed one front wheel on my car isn't centered where it should sit, and so it has a slight pull in that direction. Attached is a diagram of what I mean - what do you reckon could be the problem?

[image]

---

Edit. Aprox 1 year ago I had that side's Shock Mounts, suspension arm, axle boot and wheel bearing replaced, along with both shock absorbers, but I don't know if that could be related, given it was so long ago.

EDIT2: We're talking about a 2009 Toyota Yaris HB.

Comment: Good work on the diagram, by the way.  Pictures are good, but this is a nice alternative.

Comment: You might want to tell  us what car you have. It might be a suspension issue, but it could also be that the subframe shifted for whatever reason.

Comment: Added make and model, sorry I didn't think that was relevant. I'm not sure I understand you with "subframe shifted"

Comment: Where the subframe mounts. The tolerances aren't rock solid. There's room for adjustment. On some cars there are alignment holes in the frame you stick a bar in and tighten the mount bolts. More likely in your case though a suspension component is bent or you have bad bushings.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few front suspension issues that would be suspect, but my best guess would be the control arm bushings.  When they go bad and break, the entire control arm that holds the wheel in place can shift.  This is often accompanied by a lot of clunking noises going over bumps etc.

Of course if you ran into a curb or similar, something could be bent or broken.  If you're sure there hasn't been any impact, you'll have to start looking at suspension parts.  Jack up that wheel and pull on it and try to move it around.  It shouldn't move, and if it does, the movement will help point you to the loose  pieces.

Comment: "This is often accompanied by a lot of clunking noises going over bumps etc." That is definitely not the case, the only _symptoms_ I have are a pull towards the right (naturally, I expected this) and a vibrating steering wheel. I'll jack the car and take a look at what you mentioned, thanks for the help.

Comment: The more details the better.  If you think of anything else edit your question.  someone might have a more specific answer with more clues.  It will be something suspension related.

Comment: You're right, I edited with more info that maybe could be related, thanks again.